# Electron can't find fibers.node

Tags: electron, node-fibers

I'm getting an error in my electron app:

```
## There is an issue with node-fibers ##
...\node_modules\fibers\bin\win32-x64-57\fibers.node is missing.
```

I tried this to fix it:

```
cd .\node_modules\fibers
node build
```

And I get this output:

```
win32-x64-57 exists; testing
Binary is fine; exiting
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Using https://github.com/electron/electron-rebuild fixed the issue for me.